# Shoud I simplify the code in the question?

Tags: discussion, edits

Take a look at [Why does the second for loop only iterate once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18876594/3416774).

While the OP's code is a wall of text, the problem doesn't need to be that long. I have one and it is more simple. I think for the sake of later visitors I should change the question to mine code.

Should I?

One other problem if the answer for the above question is "yes", is the already answers based on the OP's code. So that if I change the code in the question, I should change it in the answers as well. If there are only one or two answers, I can take my time on that. But if it has more answers, well...

---

#### My proposed version:

> The text.txt:
>
> ```
> a A
> b B
> c C
> ```
>
> A simple `for` in `for`:
>
> ```
> for word in ['a','b','c']:
>     print(word)
>
>     for line in text.txt:
>         if line==word:
>             print(word,line)
> ```
>
> Result:
>
> ```
> a A
> b
> c
> ```
>
> Why is that?

Comment: I feel like there should be a canonical question for "why can't I iterate over a file twice without seeking back to the top?"

Answer (score 3):

No you should not edit the questions code sample in such a radical way.

You cannot surely know why the OP wrote this code their way. Comment instead, point out the problem and ask the OP to improve their question giving a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: but as the answers have pointed out, the error of the code is actually [the reason of it], which can be reproduce by a simpler code. I feel the need to a) make it a MCVE, or b) make a canonical question

Comment: @Ooker That's still the OP's job to do IMHO. Your proposal might improve the actual question, but aren't necessary, if the existing answers pointing that out already.